# Can i assume same app speed for same iOS device for all users

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, memory, cpu

I could not find an answer on this so I hope the answer is a sample yes.

Can I make the simple assumption that if I test my app on an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0, all users using an iPhone5 with iOS 6.0 will have the same performance --Given that all apps work in silos and are allocated a specific memory space and CPU utilization when in the foreground.

Fair assumption?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst they are allocated their own memory space, it doesn't mean they have access to all the memory available. [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) describes the problem well:

> There is a direct correlation between the amount of free memory available and the relative performance of your app. Less free memory means that the system is more likely to have trouble fulfilling future memory requests. If that happens, the system can always remove suspended apps, code pages, or other nonvolatile resources from memory. However, removing those apps and resources from memory may be only a temporary fix, especially if they are needed again a short time later. Instead, minimize your memory use in the first place, and clean up the memory you do use in a timely manner.

Also stuff like Disk access and CPU access depends on what is going around in the background. A user could have multiple mail accounts syncing and notifications firing and network signal searching and a whole heap of other stuff all of which may impact performance. If you are running into the case where you are running to the limits of performance it would be good to see where you can tune your application.

Comment: so given that the memory and CPU can be impacted by other apps and threads running on the device, is the recommended course of action here to: A) build the app to check dynamically for these issues and adjust on the fly certain algorithms or B) Just optimize the app memory usage and CPU usage to the nth degree..

Comment: Personally i'd go for option B because you'll never know when you'll somehow fall short of memory. Also make good use of the memory warnings given by the OS (didReceiveMemoryWarning) to further tune your calculations. I'd advise building the app as normal first and then optimising if needed. Pre-mature optimisations makes it more difficult in my opinion.

Comment: Also try developing on a slightly lower end device (such an iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4) because if your app behaves fine in general use on these devices then it should work even more smoothly on the iPhone 5

Comment: Thanks. With the didReceiveMemoryWarning, is it the result of mem leaks/usage within my app causing the memory warning or can that warning be equally caused by a user having many apps running in the background and my app requesting more memory than available?

Comment: I found the answer to my last question/comment regarding didReceiveMemoryWarning. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046595/ios-i-receive-memory-warnings-but-have-no-idea-why

Answer (score 0):

In most cases is true. There could be the exceptions ofc, for eg:

- if a user has so many apps opened as reach almost the memory limit of device.
- Network isuues: you are testing with a good wi-fi , but the user has poor signal at wi-fi or goes with 3G-2G.
- User has a jailbreaked phone and has custom os settings: overclock and what else not... some apps limiting other app cpu-memory-network usage and so on.